# json_object_set_string vs json_object_dotset_string in Azure IoT SDK

Tags: c, json, azure, azure-sdk

I'm using the Azure client IoT SDK for C.

When working with device twins and updating the desired state from the device, I can't seem to find a proper explanation as to what is the difference between these functions :

`json_object_set_string` vs `json_object_dotset_string`

`json_object_set_number` vs `json_object_dotset_number`

Answer (score 1):

Quoted from library header comments

> **json_object_set_string & json_object_set_number**
>
> Creates new name-value pair or frees and replaces old value with a new
> one.  json_object_set_value does not copy passed value so it shouldn't
> be freed afterwards.

> **json_object_dotset_string & json_object_dotset_number**
>
> Works like dotget functions, but creates whole hierarchy if necessary.
> json_object_dotset_value does not copy passed value so it shouldn't be freed afterwards.

Example

```
void serialization_example(void) {
    JSON_Value *root_value = json_value_init_object();
    JSON_Object *root_object = json_value_get_object(root_value);
    char *serialized_string = NULL;
    json_object_set_string(root_object, "name", "John Smith");
    json_object_set_number(root_object, "age", 25);
    json_object_dotset_string(root_object, "address.city", "Cupertino");//**
    json_object_dotset_value(root_object, "contact.emails", json_parse_string("[\"email@example.com\",\"email2@example.com\"]"));
    serialized_string = json_serialize_to_string_pretty(root_value);
    puts(serialized_string);
    json_free_serialized_string(serialized_string);
    json_value_free(root_value);
}
```

OUTPUT

```
{
    "name": "John Smith",
    "age": 25,
    "address": {
        "city": "Cupertino"
    },
    "contact": {
        "emails": [
            "email@example.com",
            "email2@example.com"
        ]
    }
}
```

for more information please check this header file.
[parson.h](https://github.com/kgabis/parson/blob/master/parson.h)

Comment: I saw this already. However, it's still not clear. dotget creates a whole hierarchy if necessary.. what does that mean exactly?

Comment: hierarchy is address(node) > city(child), its (dotset) allow to create nodes with childs hierarchical, json_object_dotset_string(root_object, "address.city", "Cupertino");